# C++ error about map and iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

With code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>> mm;

    std::map<std::string, int>::iterator iter = mm.find(1);
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Class 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int,
std::map<std::string, int>>>' is not compatible with class
'std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char>>, int>::iterator'
```

I have not compiled the code. Clion reminded me that there was an error like above.

Comment: Why not use `auto`? Would make your code more readable and reduce typing. Also; what is your question exactly? You really should post a [mcve]..

Comment: @JesperJuhl, the "minimal, complete and verifiable example" is just that two lines of code. https://ideone.com/OSGvZW

Comment: @Yury Schkatula No. A [mcve] is a *complete* program that we can copy into a file and compile ourselves. That's not possible with just your two lines - what you link to is what should be in the question.

Comment: Okay, I amended that code for people not so familiar with C++.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for you remind. I received this error from Clion before compiled it. And now I complete it.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I wanted to know why I got that error. Now I found the reason is that I used a wrong iterator type and thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You simply use the wrong type of `iter`, it should be:

```
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int>>::iterator
```

However, I would recommend to use `auto` instead to avoid such errors:

```
auto iter = mm.find(1);
```